# Wordpress + Meta box: For each field value

Tags: wordpress, foreach, clone, custom-fields, meta-boxes

I am trying to get value of each clone (adding by +) field value and want to repeat video embed code.

First I am using this wordpress meta box plugin.
http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/04/how-to-create-meta-box-wordpress-post.html

I have a CPT where I want to use one code that will display as per the number of fields. There is a text meta box on CPT where user can add more by clicking on + button means clone. So for each field user will enter different value of image ID. So I want to repeat my code as per the number of field.

So if user adds 3 field it will repeat the code 3 times. which have something this structure.

```
<div>
    <a href=""><img src="first-field-value" /></a>
</div>
```

So I want to repeat this structure as per how many field user created and entered the value for that.

I am really sorry if I unable to describe properly. But please let me know if you want to know something more than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wp Alchemy class at http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/ allows for repeating fields.

If you are rolling your own, you need to make sure that the form fields that represent your data entry are named with a trailing '[]', eg; myfieldname[]. This ensures that php treats the values for each cloned item as an array.

Comment: Alright! its fine to get nice script but having trouble to get radio, select and check box value. can you please help me for that?

Comment: Are you using Wp Alchemy or making your own metabox functions?

Comment: Are the values getting saved? You can check this by looking in the post_meta table within your wordpress database. Or, are you able to save the values, but not read them? If you are storing cloned form fields you have to iterate over the array that contains their combined values.

Comment: I am using the Alchemy script means its saving of course.. I don't understand why are you asking such question where my question is how to get value of radio, select and checkbox value to the template.. I am asking snippet for template not about saving the date to the database.. thats script does nicely I do not have to touch.

Comment: It wasn't clear that you were actually able to save any data, and just because you are using Wp Alchemy doesn't mean its working. This should work for you: http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/#template

Comment: I have gone through with this document but unable to understand how to use for radio, select and checkbox. I am able to get value for Clone object (loop) single input and textarea but not for radio, select and checkbox.